# Access return value from result() function

Tags: php, codeigniter

Trying to get the result of my query send it back to controller and return it to a view and access it there. I can't seem to display the value at my view so I tried echoing out what I got as a result from controller. It keeps stating undefined offset 1...please tell me how to access model return value properly

Model

```
$output = $this->db->query("SELECT * from incoming ORDER BY incomingId LIMIT 20");
return $output->result();
```

Controller

```
$data = $this->search_form->searchIdIncoming($searchQuery);
echo $data[0][1];
$this->load->view("searchIncoming", $data);
```

View

```
if(isset($incomingId))
    echo "Primary key is available";
```

Comment: result() returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure, try doing print_r($data); to check how you are getting the results, because $data[0][1] is definitely not the way you get the result data..

Comment: I'm getting this:Array ( [0] => Array ( [incomingId] => 5 [referenceNo] => 192301923 [documentTypeId] => 1 [documentDate] => 2014-04-24 [dateReceived] => 2014-04-24 [sender] => asdlassd [companyId] => 1 [responsibleStaffId] => 2 [subject] => adsklasd [actionDone] => asdsa [track] => 1 [completed] => 0 [remarks] => asdasklda ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work by replacing the result() function with the result_array() function in codeigniter added a few other stuff to properly get table functions but here's the result I got:

```
$rows[] = array();
        $rows2[] = array();
        $rows3[] = array();

        $i = 0;
        $companyName = $this->db->query("SELECT id, name from company");
        foreach($companyName->result_array() as $row2){
            $rows2[$i]['id'] = $row2['id'];
            $rows2[$i]['name'] = $row2['name'];
            $i++;
        }
        //get all company names

        $i = 0;
        $staffName = $this->db->query("SELECT id, surname, firstName, middleInitial from employee");
        foreach($staffName->result_array() as $row3){
            $rows3[$i]['id'] = $row3['id'];
            $rows3[$i]['name'] = $row3['surname'].", ".$row3['firstName']." ".$row3['middleInitial'];
            $i++;
        }
        //get all employee names

        $i= 0;
        $output = $this->db->query("SELECT * from incoming ORDER BY incomingId LIMIT 20");
        if ($output->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($output->result_array() as $row){
            $count = 0;
            $j = 0;
            $rows[$i]['incomingId'] = $row['incomingId'];
            $rows[$i]['referenceNo'] = $row['referenceNo'];
            $rows[$i]['documentTypeId'] = $row['documentTypeId'];
            $rows[$i]['documentDate'] = $row['documentDate'];
            $rows[$i]['dateReceived'] = $row['dateReceived'];
            $rows[$i]['sender'] = $row['sender'];

            while($count < sizeof($rows2)){
                if($rows2[$j]['id'] != $row['companyId']){
                    $j++;
                }else{
                    $rows[$i]['companyName'] = $rows2[$j]['name'];
                    break;
                }
                $count++;
            }
            $j= 0;
            $count = 0;
            while($count < sizeof($rows3)){
                if($rows3[$j]['id'] != $row['responsibleStaffId']){
                    $j++;
                }else{
                    $rows[$i]['responsibleStaffName'] = $rows3[$j]['name'];
                    break;
                }
                $count++;
            }

            $rows[$i]['subject'] = $row['subject'];
            $rows[$i]['actionDone'] = $row['actionDone'];

            $rows[$i]['track'] = $row['track'];
            $rows[$i]['completed'] = $row['completed'];
            $rows[$i]['remarks'] = $row['remarks'];
            $i++;
        }

        return $rows;
    }
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo $data[0]["Your Database field name"]; instead of echo $data[0][1];
```

like

```
echo $data[0]["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the result from model in view the most appropriate way is like this:

1) Return the resultant records from the model as an array like:

```
$output = $this->db->query("SELECT * from incoming ORDER BY incomingId LIMIT 20");
return $output->result();
```

2) Access this value in Controller by calling the function for this model query say (as you have not detailed well, I am not sure which function you are using),

```
$data['details'] = $this->search_form->searchIdIncoming($searchQuery);  // store the result in an array
```

and pass the array to the view

```
$this->load->view("searchIncoming", $data);
```

3) In the view file, you can display the records with

```
if(!empty($details))
    {
      foreach($details as $row)
      {
        if($row->incomingId!=0)
          echo "Primary key is available";
        ...........
      }
   }
```

Comment: weird...it doesn't seem to be echoing anything...just leaves the page blank after form submission

Comment: and sorry...the model code that i posted is basically what's written in searchIdIncoming function

Comment: try echoing the resultant array in model, controller and check whether you are getting values correctly..Then only it will get displayed in view.